# C Programming: A Modern Approach - chapter 10 project 6 - confused

Tags: c, stack

There are a number of people who post answers to this book's questions on github I've looked at a number of them & they all appear to be quite similar. Anyway here's a link to one of them. The question is in comments & then the answer is below it.

https://github.com/auwsmit/cpama2/blob/master/Ch10/ProgrammingProjects/p6.c

So lets assume the expression I type in is `75+=`

I can't figure out why the following lines work.

```
else if (input == '+')
            push(operandA + operandB);
```

From how I understand it,
operandA = '7' = ascii 55 & operandB = '5' = ascii 53.

So won't operandA + operandB = ascii 108 = 'l'

From here my understanding is that this character gets assigned to contents[0] which means main should eventually print out 108 as the answer, but it doesn't it. It prints out the right answer of 12.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Wrong understanding (e.g. of line 76 of that `p6.c`). Compile that code with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/) -or whatever debugger you have- to run it step by step

Comment: Look at the stack `push` calls carefully. What is actually being pushed on the stack? Hint: it isn't digit ascii character values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you see this line in the given code:

```
if (input >= '0' && input <= '9')
            push(input - '0');
```

When 7 and 5 are entered instead of 55 and 53, (55-48=7) and (53-48=5) are stored.